# Riverpod question about using ref.listenManual

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, riverpod-generator

Please check the following code below.

```
  void initState() {
   ref.listenManual(
      timerControllerProvider,
      (previous, next) {       
        if (next.remainingSeconds == 300) {
          showAlertDialogButton_1(context, "5 Minutes remaining");
        } else if (next.remainingSeconds == 0) {
                   context.goNamed(NameConstants.timeFinishPage,
             );
          
        }
      },
    ); 
}
```

My question is.. Can i use navigation from `initState` ?

Comment: That is setting up a listener, which cannot even trigger for the first time until *after* the first build() has completed, and the callback phases begin.  I would move this down into a ref.listen inside the build. The main purpose to use listenManual in initState is to be able to immediately read the current provider state within initState.

Comment: Thanks.. i will move that down into ref.listen inside build.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `fireImmediately: true` if you want to possibly show the modal immediately:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  ref.listenManual(
    provider,
    fireImmediately: true,
    (prev, next) {
      if (<something>) showModal();
    },
  );
}
```

Adding to this, you're not naturally allowed to show modals directly inside `initState`. You'll have to delay the `showModal`:

```dart
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() => showModal(...));
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use navigation just like in my question above ?

Answer (score 0):

Also works for navigation:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  ref.listenManual(
    myProvider,
    fireImmediately: true,
    (prev, next) {
      final config = next.value!;
      if (config.step == OrderStep.login) {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => context.pushReplacement(pathLogin));
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: It works but i just wanted to make sure if it is a good practice or not ?